# Redis получить значение хеша ключ которого в голове списка

Tags: redis, node-redis

Добрый день. У меня есть несколько js скриптов, которые работают на node js. Работают они с одной базой redis. Я получаю результаты сортировки в виде списка. В этом списке лежат нужные мне ключи в нужном порядке. Основная проблема в том, что я пока на одном клиенте дожидаюсь выполнения lpop, что бы получить при помощи hgetall значения нужного мне хеша. Другой клиент уже успевает удалить хеш.

Как одной командой получить значение хеша, ключ которого лежит в первом элементе листа? (Что-то на подобии hgetall (lpop list1))

Answer (score 0):

Сделал это при помощи небольшого скрипта на lua

```
eval 'return redis.pcall("hgetall",redis.pcall("lpop","lis1"))' 0
```

Вопрос закрыт